# “Error: Node is either not visible or not an HTMLElement”. Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, automation, puppeteer

I added an option to do scrollpagetobottom. with this npm.

> const scrollPageToBottom = require('puppeteer-autoscroll-down');

after it, I have a loop that should click on many elements on the page But after I use the npm to scrolldown after one click I get this error:

> Error: Node is either not visible or not an HTMLElement

```js
(async () => {
  try {
    //Launching Puppeteer
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: false,
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    //going to new Page
    await page.goto(
      'https://translatewiki.net/wiki/Special:Translate?group=%21additions&language=fr&filter=%21translated&action=translate'
    );

    //waiting for the Js to load(DOM)
    await page.waitForSelector('.tux-message');

    await scrollPageToBottom(page, 5000, 2000);
    console.log('finish scroll');
    //Clicking on Questions to Load the suggestions
    const texts = await page.$$(` div.eight.columns.tux-list-message`);
    for (const text of texts) {
      await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 100));
      await text.click();
    }
    } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
})();
```

I really don't know why it's happening hope for a master to help me.

Comment: Is this duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66136130/puppeteer-error-node-is-either-not-visible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe try

```
await page.evaluate((element) => { element.click(); }, text);
```

instead of

```
await text.click();
```

If I recall correctly, puppeteer's `elementHandle.click()` is a more complicated operation with some additional checks, so sometimes a simpler evaluated Web API `element.click()` suffices when the former fails.